# ı cant create zone with my powerdnsadmin ı saw http error 400

Tags: domain-name-system, powerdns

```
[2023-08-28 14:35:33,070] [_internal.py:224] INFO - 192.168.220.1 - - [28/Aug/2023 14:35:33] "POST /domain/add HTTP/1.1" 400 -
[2023-08-28 14:35:33,095] [_internal.py:224] INFO - 192.168.220.1 - - [28/Aug/2023 14:35:33] "GET /static/assets/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
[2023-08-28 14:35:33,106] [_internal.py:224] INFO - 192.168.220.1 - - [28/Aug/2023 14:35:33] "GET /static/assets/css/source_sans_pro.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
[2023-08-28 14:35:33,111] [_internal.py:224] INFO - 192.168.220.1 - - [28/Aug/2023 14:35:33] "GET /static/generated/main.css?aa4c2493 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
[2023-08-28 14:35:33,113] [_internal.py:224] INFO - 192.168.220.1 - - [28/Aug/2023 14:35:33] "GET /static/assets/css/roboto_mono.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
[2023-08-28 14:35:33,137] [_internal.py:224] INFO - 192.168.220.1 - - [28/Aug/2023 14:35:33] "GET /static/img/favicon.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
[2023-08-28 14:35:33,138] [_internal.py:224] INFO - 192.168.220.1 - - [28/Aug/2023 14:35:33] "GET /static/generated/main.js?a2786bcc HTTP/1.1" 304 -
[2023-08-28 14:35:33,141] [_internal.py:224] INFO - 192.168.220.1 - - [28/Aug/2023 14:35:33] "GET /user/image?username=cem HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

that is my log ı use mysql-server

that is my quarry

```
CREATE TABLE domains (
  id                    INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name                  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  master                VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  last_check            INT DEFAULT NULL,
  type                  VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  notified_serial       INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  account               VARCHAR(40) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' DEFAULT NULL,
  options               VARCHAR(64000) DEFAULT NULL,
  catalog               VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) Engine=InnoDB CHARACTER SET 'latin1';

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX name_index ON domains(name);
CREATE INDEX catalog_idx ON domains(catalog);


CREATE TABLE records (
  id                    BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  domain_id             INT DEFAULT NULL,
  name                  VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  type                  VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  content               VARCHAR(64000) DEFAULT NULL,
  ttl                   INT DEFAULT NULL,
  prio                  INT DEFAULT NULL,
  disabled              TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0,
  ordername             VARCHAR(255) BINARY DEFAULT NULL,
  auth                  TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) Engine=InnoDB CHARACTER SET 'latin1';

CREATE INDEX nametype_index ON records(name,type);
CREATE INDEX domain_id ON records(domain_id);
CREATE INDEX ordername ON records (ordername);


CREATE TABLE supermasters (
  ip                    VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  nameserver            VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  account               VARCHAR(40) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ip, nameserver)
) Engine=InnoDB CHARACTER SET 'latin1';


CREATE TABLE comments (
  id                    INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  domain_id             INT NOT NULL,
  name                  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  type                  VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  modified_at           INT NOT NULL,
  account               VARCHAR(40) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' DEFAULT NULL,
  comment               TEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) Engine=InnoDB CHARACTER SET 'latin1';

CREATE INDEX comments_name_type_idx ON comments (name, type);
CREATE INDEX comments_order_idx ON comments (domain_id, modified_at);


CREATE TABLE domainmetadata (
  id                    INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  domain_id             INT NOT NULL,
  kind                  VARCHAR(32),
  content               TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) Engine=InnoDB CHARACTER SET 'latin1';

CREATE INDEX domainmetadata_idx ON domainmetadata (domain_id, kind);


CREATE TABLE cryptokeys (
  id                    INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  domain_id             INT NOT NULL,
  flags                 INT NOT NULL,
  active                BOOL,
  published             BOOL DEFAULT 1,
  content               TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
) Engine=InnoDB CHARACTER SET 'latin1';

CREATE INDEX domainidindex ON cryptokeys(domain_id);


CREATE TABLE tsigkeys (
  id                    INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name                  VARCHAR(255),
  algorithm             VARCHAR(50),
  secret                VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) Engine=InnoDB CHARACTER SET 'latin1';

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX namealgoindex ON tsigkeys(name, algorithm);
```

that is my dig input

```
; <<>> DiG 9.18.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.2-Ubuntu <<>> @127.0.0.1
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 25775
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;.                              IN      NS

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Mon Aug 28 14:40:34 UTC 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 28
```

powerdns and pdnsadmin is work but ı cant create zone

that is my pdns status code

```
goktug pdns_server[21185]: WARNING: MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Aug 28 13:59:55 goktug pdns_server[21185]: WARNING: MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Aug 28 14:04:55 goktug pdns_server[21185]: WARNING: MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Aug 28 14:09:55 goktug pdns_server[21185]: WARNING: MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Aug 28 14:14:55 goktug pdns_server[21185]: WARNING: MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Aug 28 14:19:55 goktug pdns_server[21185]: WARNING: MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Aug 28 14:24:55 goktug pdns_server[21185]: WARNING: MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Aug 28 14:29:55 goktug pdns_server[21185]: WARNING: MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Aug 28 14:34:55 goktug pdns_server[21185]: WARNING: MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Aug 28 14:39:55 goktug pdns_server[21185]: WARNING: MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
```